# Django | Por algún error, dos url diferentes apuntan al mismo template

Tags: django, django-urls

Por algún error, tanto la url **preguntas/** como la url **categorias/** me apuntan al template **pregunta.html** La url **categorías/** debería apuntar al template **categoria.html** ejecutando "def categoria_list" . ¿Qué hago mal?

project>**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('preguntas/', include('pregunta.urls')),
    path('categorias/', include('pregunta.urls')),
]
```

preguntas>**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',
        views.pregunta_list,
        name='preguntas',
    ),
    path('categorias/',
        views.categoria_list,
        name='categorias',
    ),
]
```

preguntas>**views.py**

```
def pregunta_list(request):
    preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter().order_by('id')
    paginator = Paginator(preguntas,1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    preguntas = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'pregunta/pregunta.html', {'preguntas': preguntas})

def categoria_list(request):
    categorias = Categoria.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'pregunta/categoria.html', {'categorias': categorias})
```

Answer (score 0):

La url queda compuesta: pregunta/categoria/ Funciona bien.

```
{% url 'pregunta/categoria/' %}
```

Gracias.